# break with gdb on label in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, gdb, label, breakpoints

can I have gdb break on the label "gdbStatement:" in this example Code:

...

```
        op1 = op2 = op3 = op4 = nil;
        op1 = [ops firstObject];
        if(jj>1)op2 = [ops oai:1];
        if(jj>2)op3 = [ops oai:2];
        if(jj>3)op4 = [ops oai:3];

gdbStatement:
// Wertzuweisungen
        if([stmt isZuweisung]){
// ausser bei mutable Targets, die erweitert werden oder im Fehlerfall hier drin kein continue, weil am Ende s1 weiterverarbeitet wird;
            NSString *val1,*s1;
            double varVal=0;
```

...

I know how to break on line numbers and functions. But can't find how to break on labels.

Comment: did you try by dragging it to next statements ?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya from his question, I would assume he's not using Xcode or another graphical debugger front end.

Comment: @mah: Then I dont know who to use breakpoints through console ... !!!

Comment: right, I'm not using Xcode; plain gdb on commandline;

Comment: The label doesn't appear in the symbol list (tested using `nm` on an object file) so I very much doubt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FSF or apple gdb? The below applies to FSF gdb.

Assuming that the code is in a method, there appears to be no way to specify a breakpoint on a label in a method,

The syntax for specifying a breakpoint on a label is break function:label
but the Objective-C linespec parser in FSF gdb does not parse this, so break -[aClass aMethod]:aLabel doesn't work

One could reasonably assume that you could mangle the method specify a function breakpoint on the symbol name, like 'break _i_aClass__aMethod:label', but that doesn't currently work either for a reason I do not yet understand.

tried with gdb 7.3 and 7.6.

Comment: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.0.1-debian